# Divide by zeros in a multi-variable function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to define a function, based on order of the function `n` and the input `x`.

```
import numpy as np
#importing our packages

n = np.array([0,1,2])
x = np.arange(0,21,1)

#defining our  functions 


def J(n,x):

    if np.all(n==0) and np.all(x==0): 
        return 0
    else:   
        J0 = np.sin(x)/x
        J0[np.isnan(J0)]=0
        print("First function J0 is",J0)

    if np.all(n==1) and np.all(x==0):
        return 0
    else:
        J1 = np.sin(x)/(x**2)-np.cos(x)/x
        J1[np.isnan(J1)]=0
        print("Second function J1 is",J1)

    #J2
    g = ((3/x**2)-1)
    if np.all(n==2) and np.all(x==0):
        return 0
    else:
        J2 = g*J0-3*np.cos(x)/x**2 
        J2[np.isnan(J2)]=0
        print("Third function J2 is",J2)
```

I've managed to write the above.

I've got some issues I'd like your help with:

1. I've had to include `Jn[np.isnan(Jn)]=0` as without it, the first element of my result will return nan otherwise. (Which shows my if statement doesn't work)
2. How to get rid of the plethora of warnings, namely 'divide by zero' and 'invalid value encountered in true_divide'? I realise this links backs to problem 1 and is due to my code still dividing by zero for an odd reason.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Your code will not work, see line `def J(n,x):` and the following. Please update accordingly.

Comment: Your posted code fails to execute on many counts.  Please return to your Python tutorials on indentation and syntax of basic statements.  When you have this corrected such that it produces the one problem that requires our help, you're ready to post a question.

Comment: Your def line needs to be followed by an indent and your first else needs to come after the if.... typo I presume?

Answer (score 1):

In general, a useful way to avoid 'divide by zero' warnings or errors is to use the `np.divide` function.
You should specify what you want the problematic values to be instead of infinity - in this example, zeros.

```
c = np.divide(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a), where=b!=0)
```